# Why am I getting "SyntaxError:" on OS X Python 3.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, osx-yosemite

I just got a new MackBook Pro and installed Python 3.4.
I ran the terminal and typed

```
python3.4
```

I got:

```
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 23 2015, 02:52:03) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I typed:

```
>>> print("Hello world") 
Hello world
```

All good, but when I tried to do something a bit more complex I ran into trouble, I did:

```
>>>counter = 5
>>>
>>> while counter > 0:
...     counter -= 1
...     print()
... print("Hello World")
```

I get the error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 4
print("Hello World")
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My guess is that the error is on the 'print("Hello World")' but I have no clue as to why, I don't need to indent it if I want it to run after the loop is finished. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have to make two lines!

Comment: Stupid interpreter. It's not even the right kind of error. It should be `IndentationError`!

Comment: Get ipython for yourself

Comment: I have PyCharm, but I wanted to try it on Terminal, cuz I've never used it b4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice the "..." prompt? That's telling you that the interactive interpreter knows you are in a block. You'll have to enter a blank line to terminate the block, before doing the final print statement.

This is an artifact of running interactively -- the blank line isn't required when you type your code into a file.

Comment: but how do I run the `print("Hello World")` without having to run the `while` first? Do I have to build then into a function if I want to run them together one after the other?

Comment: @lokilindo:  You can't. I assume that is why you un-indented the final print statement. If you want it to be part of the loop, indent it to be in the loop. If you want it after, enter a blank line. The while loop will run, and then the final print statement will run. That's just how interactive mode works.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is syntax error.

```
>>> while counter > 0:
...     counter -= 1
...     print()
... print("Hello World")
```

this is how python console works - you can see that you have three dots before print('hello world') which indicates that python still expects **indendted** code that belongs to while block.

You need to double-press enter in order to get to normal mode. (Signalized by >>>). Also in future if you encounter similar problems always try to run them from file and not only from console.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a quirk of python's interactive mode, which treats newlines specially.

When you have a `...` prompt, it *must* be followed by a continuation of the preceding compound statement, rather than the beginning of a new statement, which it would in non-interactive mode. Press enter again to make the `...` prompt go away.

---

Observer that this fails:

```
echo $'while False: pass\npass' | python -i
```

But this works:

```
echo $'while False: pass\npass' | python
```

---

You can read the nitty-gritty details [in the grammar reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html). Interactive input uses the `single_input` start state, and non-interactive input uses the `file_input` start state.

Answer (score -2):

You have to use space for indentation (and ";" to separate two instruction :

```
>>> counter = 5
>>> while counter > 0:
    counter -= 1
    print("Hello")


Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
>>>
```

Comment: The OP _is_ using spaces for indentation. I think you've missed the point of the question. Normally, removing one level of indentation ends a block, but it doesn't when running interactively.

Comment: Please, why "-1"? Thanks in advance

Comment: @BryanOakley: So I've try to explain it in the answer. But sometimes tab do not work well in shell, but space work everywhere. And to separate instruction well you have to use ";". No? I'm not right?

Comment: @ Clodion I think they "-1"ed you because you missed part of the explanation. I didn't want to run "Hello World" five times, I wanted to run it AFTER the five spaces of the while loop. Apparently it can't be done without first running the while loop. (unless I do it within a function/method). I still appreciate you trying to help me, I am sorry you got down voted.

Comment: @lokilindo: yes. I put "hello" just for figuring empty lines. It was to show that he have to put it after `while` is finished. And I've said it in my first comment (just below is question).